# c# function returning letters from a string that aren't in another

Tags: c#, string

Let's say I have two strings:   `main_word: 'abcdefa'` and `check_word: 'abcd'` .

**I know that the letters from `check_word` are all in the `main_word`.**

I have to write a function that would return me the rest of the `main_word` after 'using all the letters to form the check_word. In the above example the function would return the string `efa`.

Here's my code:

```
private static string getResidue(string, main_word, string check_word)
{
    string result = "";
    bool isFound;

    foreach (char c in main_word)
    {
        isFound = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < check_word.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (c == check_word[i])
            {
                //check_word[i] = 'x'; mark as used (this doesn't work) 
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isFound) result += c;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The problem is that this version doesn't support duplicates of letters. I commented the version that would solve my problem, but unfortunately, the c# doesn't allow that line because the `property of indexer cannot be assigned to - it is read only`.
Any ideas how to make this function work as intended?

Comment: `Enumerable.Except`, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, you cannot delete or replace a character in a `string`, because `string` is **immutable** in C#.

One way to solve this is to maintain a **mutable** collection of characters. For example, if you copied all the characters from the string to another collection (for example, a `List<char>`), then you would be able to remove items from it.

You can use the Linq method `check_list.ToList()` to convert the `string` to a `List<char>`.

Comment: Or he could just call `ToArray()` on the `check_word`!

Comment: @Franky You're right, an array would also work. But a list is neater in my opinion, because you can remove items from a list, but you can only replace items in an array.

Comment: That's true, it just means an additional reference.

Comment: Thank you for a nice portion of new inrofmation :) Problem solved, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

As I apparently can't read nor understand the simplest things in the language called english such as letters, here's the update;

```
var a = "abcdefa";
var b = "abcd";

var c = b.ToCharArray().ToList();
var res = a.ToCharArray().Where(x => !c.Remove(x));
```

this yields the result 'e', 'f' AND 'a' and works no matter how you twist and turn the list.

Comment: I specified that it should return 'efa' (so the repeated letter does appear in the result)

Answer (score 0):

this may work for you:

```
public string getResidue(string main_word, string check_word)
{
    foreach (char c in check_word)
    {
        int idx = main_word.IndexOf(c);
        if (idx > -1)
        {
            main_word = main_word.Remove(idx, 1);
        }
    }
    return main_word;
}
```